# Get Int value out of Signal Int

Tags: dom, elm

I am facing issue in taking `Int` value out of `Window.dimensions`'s return val - `Signal Int`.

```
view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  let wx = Signal.map fst Window.dimensions 
      wy = Signal.map snd Window.dimensions  
  in fromElement <| container wx wy middle <| toElement  100 100 <|
      div []
        [ button [ onClick address Decrement ] [text "-"]
        ]
```

This line, `wx = Signal.map fst Window.dimensions` to get `window` container x-coordinates throws error as,

```
Type mismatch between the following types on line 30, column 31 to 33:
        Signal.Signal In
        Int
    It is related to the following expression:
        wx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Window.dimensions` is a `Signal (Int, Int)`. Mapping over it with `fst` or `snd` will give you a `Signal Int` which you can't just get "the value out of".

Your `view` shouldn't have `Signal` in it at all. It should just take some state in and return some `Html`. If you want to make a `container` that is the same dimensions as the screen, better to have your `view` function take the width/height and then map your view function over `Window.dimensions`. You can use [this](http://elm-lang.org/examples/mouse-tracker) as an example.

Comment: hey thanks robert.. but my main method code is based on `StartApp.Start` which takes `model, view, and  update` arguments. the graphics example given by you is not based on a mvc pattern. I am wondering, even when i use `main = Signal.map` it will listen only to those `Window` signals and not to the user clicks...

Comment: If you want to start passing more arguments to your view then it sounds like your program may have outgrown `StartApp` :-P Time to write your own `main`!

Comment: oops.. that is a bit sarcastic.. anways, my idea is to have an extra `action` as `resize` just like `increment`/`decrement` and trigger the action from `onresize` from inside the view function....

Comment: You could put the screen dimensions in your model and and trigger updates the same way `increment`/`decrement` do, but you'd have to guess at the initial screen dimensions when initializing your model to pass to `StartApp.start`. So if the screen dimensions never changed, the view would never center